# Set theory. Is $\varnothing \in \{1,2,3\}$ true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$.

Is the following expression true then?

$\varnothing \in A$.

I'm having issue understanding if the empty set is an element of $A$. Would love a brief explanation of why it is or isn't.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The things between the braces are the elements of $A$. Answering the question "Is $4\in A$?" is precisely the same difficulty as "Is $\emptyset\in A$?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

$A$ is a set with three elements, namely $1,2$, and $3$.  Since $\emptyset$ is none of these three, $\emptyset\notin A$.

It is indeed true that $\emptyset \subseteq A$.  This means that each element of $\emptyset$ is also an element of $A$.  Since $\emptyset$ has no elements, this statement is vacuously true, i.e. $\emptyset\subseteq S$ for all sets $S$.  In fact even $\emptyset\subseteq\emptyset$.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not an element of $A$. It is a subset of $A$, which we denoted $\varnothing \subset A$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not positively certain someone proved $\emptyset \subseteq X$:

Let there be a set $X$ such that $\emptyset \nsubseteq X$. So there exist $x \in \emptyset$ such that $x \notin X$. Wait, what?
QED ;-)

Comment: I find this line of reasoning to be rather convincing to students who are uneasy with the usual appeal to the vacuous conditional $x \in \emptyset \Rightarrow x \in X$.

Comment: @AustinMohr I'm not sure if your comment was a positive or negative remark..? Furthermore, It might be rationally/intelectually vacuous, but I'm not sure It's *mathematically* vacuous. What do you think? Furthermore, I actually had this as an exercise in chapter $0$ of Linear-Algebra I... :-)

Comment: The statement "$x \in \emptyset \Rightarrow x \in X$" is vacuously true in a [precise sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). Since there are no elements in the set $\emptyset$, the hypothesis "$x \in \emptyset$" is always false, and therefore the conditional as a whole is always true. (By the way, my remark about your answer was intended to be favorable.)

Comment: @AustinMohr I agree that the formal (And a *tad* un-intuitive) definition of implication should be acquired prior to elements of naive set theory. It is not the case though in formal education, at least in my country.

Answer (score 1):

You must take care to the definitions.

For every set $A = \{ a_1, a_2, ...a_n, ... \}$ its *elements* are the "things" between the braces.

The *emptyset* is defined as $\forall x (x \notin \emptyset)$, and is denoted also as $\{ \}$, in order to show that it has **no** *elements*.

The definition of $A \subseteq B$ is

> $$\forall x (x \in A \rightarrow x \in B)$$

i.e.

> "every object that is an *element* of $A$ is also an *element* of $B$".

Now, if you apply this condition to $\emptyset \subseteq B$, by properties of conditional ($\rightarrow$) you may check that it is always satisfied, for every $B$, because of the above definition of $\emptyset$ : no $x$ is in $\emptyset$ and so ($P \rightarrow Q$ is *true* when $P$ is *false*) $\emptyset$ is a *subset* of every set.

> But $x \in B$ is a different relation from $A \subseteq B$.

In your example, $1$ and $2$ and $3$ are the *elements* of $A$; so we have that $B = \{ 1,2 \}$ is a *subset* of $A$.

But $\emptyset$ is not "listed" between the braces, so it is **not** an element of $A$.

Of course, being a *subset* of every set, we have $\emptyset \subseteq A$.